# Dynamically add html elements and event handlers by using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I added 3 div elements in the form and add event handler for each of them dynamically. It is supposed to popup a message showing that div's id. However, no matter which box I click, it popups the last div's id which is 10175.

Any input will be appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  .empty
          {
            background-color: green;
          }
   .safebox
          {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: 20px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
        width: 60px;
        height: auto;
          }
</style>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function ClickMe(elem){
        alert(elem.id);
    };

   window.onload=function(){
    var tempdiv = document.createElement('div');
    var text = document.createTextNode('0173');
    tempdiv.className='safebox empty';
    tempdiv.appendChild(text);
    tempdiv.setAttribute('id','10173');
    tempdiv.appendChild(text);
    document.getElementById('pagewarpper').appendChild(tempdiv);

    var currentdiv = document.getElementById('10173');
    if (currentdiv.addEventListener){
       currentdiv.addEventListener('click', function(){ClickMe(currentdiv);}, false);
    }
    else {
      currentdiv.attachEvent('onclick', function(){ClickMe(currentdiv);});
    }

    var tempdiv = document.createElement('div');
    var text = document.createTextNode('0174');
    tempdiv.className='safebox empty';
    tempdiv.appendChild(text);
    tempdiv.setAttribute('id','10174');
    tempdiv.appendChild(text);
    document.getElementById('pagewarpper').appendChild(tempdiv);

    var currentdiv = document.getElementById('10174');
    if (currentdiv.addEventListener){
       currentdiv.addEventListener('click', function(){ClickMe(currentdiv);}, false);
    }
    else {
      currentdiv.attachEvent('onclick', function(){ClickMe(currentdiv);});
    }

    var tempdiv = document.createElement('div');
    var text = document.createTextNode('0175');
    tempdiv.className='safebox empty';
    tempdiv.appendChild(text);
    tempdiv.setAttribute('id','10175');
    tempdiv.appendChild(text);
    document.getElementById('pagewarpper').appendChild(tempdiv);

    var currentdiv = document.getElementById('10175');
    if (currentdiv.addEventListener){
       currentdiv.addEventListener('click', function(){ClickMe(currentdiv);}, false);
    }
    else {
      currentdiv.attachEvent('onclick', function(){ClickMe(currentdiv);});
    }
      }
     </script>
   </header>
  <body>
 <form>
 <div id="pagewarpper">
</div>
  </form>
 </body>
```

Comment: This is a closure issue - `currentdiv` is the last `<div>` so all the functions, when they do `ClickMe(currentdiv)` are actually passing the last one. You can make it completely independent though, and use `this` instead of `currentdiv` inside the listerner.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ClickMe(this);
```

With currentDiv you are creating a closure, which points to the same object for 3 divs. The last one.